# Why doesn't JSON support integer?

Tags: json

The semantics of integers and doubles are quite different. Lua recently also added integer support (even though as a subtype of number). Python in a sense is perfect in its type completeness, I am not even talking about other more heavy weight languages like C++/C#/Java ...

There are systems that treats integers significantly different than floating point numbers (or doubles), and while using JSON, it imposes some mental damage that all the integers writing to the wire come back as doubles. On the high level application logic, one could probably differentiate based on the property, but the extra double to int cast makes the code not intuitive and misleading - people would ask questions like: why you do a cast here? Are you sure this is an integer?

So in a sense, the intent is not completely clear when there is no explicit integer support.

Can anyone shed some lights?

Thanks!

Comment: because json is based on javascript ([J]ava[S]cript [O]bject [N]otation), and in JS, all numbers are floats...

Comment: Yes, I understand that JSON has a root in JavaScript. However, I am wondering that language designers of Lua (prior 5.3)/Javascript just don't care much about integers at all? :-)